# Converse of data-processing inequality holds?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, information-theory

Data processing inequality can be stated as follows:

> If $X,Y,Z$ form a Markov chain then $I(X;Z) \le I(X,Y)$ with equality
>   if and only if $X,Z,Y$ form a Markov chain.

Does the converse follow? If not can you give a counterexample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The converse does not follow, here is a simple counterexample:

Let a Gaussian RV $X$ be observed twice with different measurement noise: I.e., let $Y=X+N_1$ and $Z=X+N_2$, where $N_1$ and $N_2$ are Gaussian RVs with different variances. If the variance of $N_1$ is larger than the variance of $N_2$, it follows that $I(X;Y)\le I(X;Z)$. Nevertheless, the Markov tuple $X-Y-Z$ does not hold. In fact, we have here the Markov tuple $Y-X-Z$.